# SQL: (Assertion) value of a column should be equal to the number of rows belonging to user ID in another table

Tags: sql, assertion

I have these tables:

```
Database (databaseId, databaseName, ServerId, NumberOfTables)  
User (userId, userName, numberOfDatabases) 
PermissionAccess (userId, databaseId, permission)
```

I'm trying to make an assertion so that the numberOfDatabases value will equal the number of rows in PermissionAccess belonging to the UserID.

Would something like this work?

```
CREATE ASSERTION DatabasesNumber
CHECK ( (SELECT numberOfDatabases FROM User U GROUP BY U.userID WHERE numberOfDatabases = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM PermissionAccess) ) );
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: No current database supports `create assertion`

Comment: This is merely a theory question! I know it doesn't support it anymore.